# How to copy a current Kubernetes resource configuration?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How to copy/ backup an existing kubernetes resource and its related entities as well as a backup option

for example when I run `kubectl get deploy my-deployment  -n staging  > backupdeploy.yaml`

I get a file named backupdeploy.yaml with all the annotations and creation timestamps.

I need to be able to achieve a copy of the original my-deployment.yaml and the related resources in separate yamls.
is there any shell script available to do this?

I also need the secrets, configmaps, svc, pvc that are tied to the " **my-deployment** "

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that you need to use the `--export` export flag:

> If true, use 'export' for the resources. Exported resources are
>   stripped of cluster-specific information.

So it would look like something like this: `kubectl get deploy my-deployment -n staging --export`

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score -1):

Try running `kubectl get pod <pod_name> -o yaml --export` but it's getting deprecated and no longer possible to use it; You can always try live editing it `kubectl edit <pod>/<pod_name>` But the first command should help enough